# testing soql in apex with the developer console

Tags: apex, soql, debugging

I put this code into the execute anonymous windows:

```
List<Id> ids =  new List<Id>(new Map<Id, Account>([select Id from Account]).keySet());
system.debug(ids);
```

I get a list of ids in the log as expected.  But then when running a test:

```
@IsTest
public class AccountProcessorTest {

static testMethod void testCountContacts(){
    Test.startTest();
    List<Id> ids =  new List<Id>(new Map<Id, Account>([select Id from Account]).keySet());
    system.debug(ids);
    AccountProcessor.countContacts(ids);
    List<Account> testers = [select Id, number_of_contacts__c, (Select Id from Contacts) from Account where Id in :ids];
    for (Account test :testers){
        System.assertEquals(test.number_of_contacts__c,test.contacts.size());            
    }
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

I get nothing, ids is null.  Then, of course, when I pass it into my actual controller to test, it doesn't work.  Is there a way to step through the code to see if it works.  I know its all run on the server etc. but google figured it out with their google sheets, etc.  salesforce can't do the same thing?

Comment: Ids is *not* null. It is *empty*. Please do not confuse the two; they are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Environment is different than your actual org environment.

1. When you run Execute Anon you get real data from Org
2. Test class runs in isolation and does not have acces to real world data(few exceptions)

According to Salesforce:

> By default, existing organization data isn’t visible to test methods,
>   with the exception of certain setup objects. You should create test
>   data for your test methods whenever possible. However, test code saved
>   against Salesforce API version 23.0 or earlier has access to all data
>   in the organization. Data visibility for tests is covered in more
>   detail in the next section.

You have set up accounts and Contac before hand before testing. 
Src : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data.htm

That been said, you can use`@isTest(SeeAllData=true)` , but this is considered as bad practise and should be avoided unless needed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are **not** getting **any ids** in your test class is because you are are trying to use *Ids* of existing accounts as in your org. To be able to use that,  you will need to use `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)` here. Refer to the documentation for [details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_seealldata_using.htm).

To avoid such scenarios in unit test cases, its always recommended that you create test data within the test class. Refer to [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_utility_classes.htm) for more details on data factory approach.